# How to get users tagged in a photo from Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How can I get public content of all the users tagged in a specific picture, is it possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this API to get media:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

or

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/shortcode/{short-code}?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

the JSON response will have `users_in_photo` which will have all the users tagged in the photo

https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

Answer (score 0):

Since this features was developed after instagram guys had deprecated their official client, the only way to get it is using a maintained fork.
If you use python you will be able to use this one, it allows you to get the data you need.
Here a sample script:

```
#install last version of maintained fork
#sudo pip install --upgrade git+https://github.com/MabrianOfficial/python-instagram
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI
access_token = "YOUR-TOKEN"
api          = InstagramAPI(access_token = access_token)
count        = 33     #max count allowed
max_id       = ''     #the most recent posts
hashtag      = 'cats' #sample hashtag
next_url     = ''     #first iteration
while True:
    result, next_url = api.tag_recent_media(count, max_id, hashtag,with_next_url=next_url)
    for m in result:
        if m.users_in_photo: 
            for uip in m.users_in_photo:
                print "user: {} -> {}".format(uip.user.username, uip.user.id)
                print "position : ({},{})".format(uip.position.x, uip.position.y)
```